# Among twins, who is the eldest?

Tags: birth

Among twins who is considered the eldest? Is it the one conceived first OR the one who comes out of womb ("born") first?

If the first conceived, then how it is determined?

In Manu Bhashya, Medatithi [describes](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201498.html) different views. Looking for firm statements from scriptures.

Comment: Not exactly. There are some which determined by who's conceived first or who the father sees first. Not interested in explanations based on medical or modern laws.

Comment: hmm, in your quote itself, there is discussion by ācāryas on this 
*According to Rāghavānanda the meaning of the second half is that since between twins the one born first is the last conceived, the right of primogeniture is given to the son born last. This is the view hinted at by a passage in the Uttaracarita, where Lava says of his brother ‘prasvakrameṇa sa kīla jyāyān.’ (Act IV).*

Comment: *Vīramitrodaya adds:—Between twins seniority is determined by birth in the womb; i.e., that child is ‘elder’ who is the first to be born in the mother’s womb; while the one born, i.e. conceived, later is regarded as junior; and it is not that seniority belongs to the child that comes out of the womb first; this conclusion is based on the fact that the child born later has been conceived earlier and would have been born earlier also, had not its passage outside been obstructed by the second child conceived later; the order of conception being the reverse of that of birth*

Comment: *It is only when both children are born simultaneously that seniority belongs to one whose face the father sees first—It goes on to add that this view has been held by ‘some people’ and in reality seniority must be determined by the priority of actual birth coming out of the womb.*

Comment: I was wrong in my first comment to this post, and I have deleted it. But I think, the notes of G. Jha do answer your question. Vīramitrodaya clears up the entire issue. Basically, based on the Vīramitrodaya & Rāghavānanda's comm., among twins generally, the elder sibling is the one who is delivered later, while younger sibling is the one who is delivered earlier. This is because the order of conception is the inverse of the order of delivery.